# Dismiss Keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, dismiss

So I have a self created top bar controller that is being implemented in my other controllers views.  I have a textfield on this top bar.  I was wondering what the best approach to having the keyboard dismiss if the user clicks anywere outside the keyboard.  I do have a tap gesture recognizer that performs the method dismisskeyboard.  However, this only works if the user clicks on the top bar outside the keyboard.  Is there a way to set it up so if the user clicks anywere on the screen, then this will dismiss the keyboard?

Comment: add tap gesture on self.view...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I would describe is a hack but still works.

1. create a transparent `UIButton` with the frame of the `view`, like below:

   ```
   UIButton* overlay = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   overlay.frame = self.view.bounds;
   overlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   [overlay addTarget:self action:@selector(hideOverlay:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
   [self.view.subviews[0] insertSubview:overlay belowSubview:self.textField];
   ```
2. Create a method `hideOverlay` to dismiss the keyboard and hide the transparent:

   ```
   -(void)hideOverlay:(id)sender {
       UIView* overlay = sender;
       [overlay removeFromSuperview];
       [self.textField resignFirstResponder];
   }
   ```

You should ideally call the first block of code in `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` protocol method of `UITextFieldDelegate` and you should register your calling class accordingly.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help.  The problem I am facing though is that I need to make my top bar controller's frame the whole screen now.  But when I do this, it makes it so the parents controllers buttons are not working since they are behind the top bar's view now (they still are visible though).  Is there a way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

You might try giving the text field a transparent inputAccessoryView, sized to fill the rest of the screen, that catches taps and dismisses the keyboard.